# Update Statement - Import Photos

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to import a photo from a folder on my desktop into a SQL Database, I have created the SQL below but I seem to be missing something and I don't know what (I am new to all this).

Can you help me?

```
USE Racing
Update RaceTracks 
SET RaceTrackPicture
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Pictures for Database\Racecourses\Cheltenham-Racecourse.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) rs
WHERE RaceTracksID = '11'
```

Thanks

Wayne

Answer (score 1):

```
USE Racing
Update RaceTracks 
SET RaceTrackPicture =
   (SELECT * 
   FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Pictures for Database\Racecourses\Cheltenham-Racecourse.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) as rs)
WHERE RaceTracksID = '11'
```